# Closeness the eigenvalues of a Matrix to a list of numbers

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$, and $\ell$ a list of $n$ numbers sorted in some order (say, decreasing).

Let $\lambda_i(A)$ be the $i$th eigenvalue of $A$ with respect to the chosen order.

Finally, let $d(A,\ell) = ||\lambda(A)-\ell||_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^n |\lambda_i(A)-\ell_i|$ be the [taxicab metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

My question is as follows:

> Given, $A,B,\ell$, is it possible to determine which of $d(A,\ell)$ or $d(B,\ell)$ is smaller **without** computing the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

**Note**: The $d(A,\ell)$ can also be any other meaningful metric that determines the matrix which its eigenvalues are closer to the list $\ell$

---

## Update: My solution (Not working!)

Let $\lambda$ and $\beta$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Clearly $det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ and $det(B-\beta I) = 0$ and $P_n(\lambda), P_n(\beta)$ are characteristic polynomial of $A,B$.

Let sort the eigenvalues $\beta = \{\beta_1,\beta_2,...\beta_n \}$ and $\lambda = \{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...\lambda_n \}$ in chosen order (say, decreasing).

Let $\forall \ell_i \in \ell, i\in\{1,2,...,n\},$

if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (det(A-\ell_i I)-det(B-\ell_i I)) > 0$ then eigenvalues of $B$ are closer to $\ell$ and if   $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (det(A-\ell_i I)-det(B-\ell_i I)) < 0$ then eigenvalues of $A$ are closer to $\ell$. Notice, since we don't actually need to calculate the eigenvalues of $A, B$, we don't need to solve the characteristic polynomial of $A, B$, It is enough to form the $det(A-\ell_i I)-det(B-\ell_i I)$, where $\ell_i$ is known then continue as described.

> Is this solution right? and is it easier to find determinant of $n$ matrices than finding the eigenvalues of a $n \times n$ matrix?

Comment: @AlexSilva thanks

Comment: Yeah! I made a mistake. I will think in another solution.

Comment: @AlexSilva I updated my question and provided a solution. Please take a look at it.

Comment: [Costs of determinant calculation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93501/what-is-the-fastest-numeric-method-for-determinant-calculation) [Costs of eigenvalue calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713878/how-expensive-is-it-to-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix) and [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Hessenberg_and_Tri-diagonal_matrices) The cost of eigenvalue calculation is about twice the costs of LU needed for determinant calculation. If you need $n>2$ determinants you are better off with eigenvalue calculation.

Comment: By the way your assumption is wrong: $l_i=0$, $A=\mathbf{1}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}n&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{0}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. $d(A,l)=n$, $d(B,l)=n$, $\operatorname{det}(A-l_i\mathbf{1})=1$, $\operatorname{det}(B-l_i\mathbf{1})=0$.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't believe it can be done; e.g., computing the eigenvalues is necessary.  For me, it's the non-monotonic nature of the metric---the absolute value in $|\lambda_i(A)-\ell_i|$. If you want to redefine "closer", and choose a different metric, that may help, but I am skeptical nonetheless.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks a lot. Is there any meaningful metric to determine the closeness without computing the eigenvalues?

Comment: The Frobenius norm, perhaps?